# Is there any way to turn a PC into a Chromecast receiver?

Tags: streaming, dlna, chromecast

I have an Intel Compute Stick, which is a Stick PC running Windows 10 which plugs into your TV via HDMI.  My question is, is there any way to turn it into a Chromecast receiver, i.e. make it so that my iPhone thinks the PC is a Chromecast, so I can cast content from various apps onto the PC?

Note that I'm already aware of DLNA streaming, but I want the convenience of using any app I want that supports Google Cast.

Comment: Windows 10 does miracast natively which *some* android phones seem to support.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely.  The Chromecast API was more open than it is now, and there were apps like Leapcast that could emulate a receiver.  They no longer work as the API was restricted.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you want/need is Chromecast, but Chrome can cast instances of itself to another PC, possibly supporting iOS. Check for add-ons. Otherwise, you can use VNC (or other RDP) from your iPhone to theoretically see the PC screen. Now, you are casting a large screen to a small one, so keep that in mind, it will be hard to use, but for watching a movie, might work alright - maybe.

Comment: I want to do the opposite: take content from my iPhone and cast it onto my computer.